# Writing this as a formal proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

The question from Velleman's *How to Prove It* section 3.1 is as follows:

Suppose $ A \setminus B \subseteq C \cap D $ and $ x \in A. $ Prove that if $ x \notin D$ then $x \in B$

My logical form of the statement is:

$x \in A \land x \in B \rightarrow x \in C \land x \in D$ and $ x \subseteq A$

I am unsure of how to properly express this as a proof. There is this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326601/if-a-b-%E2%8A%86-c-%E2%88%A9-d-and-x-%E2%88%88-a-prove-that-if-x-is-not-in-d-then-x-%E2%88%88-b).

But that thread doesn't show a written out proof.

Also, are you allowed to do the contrapositive of a given? Because if I am, then I could apply demorgan's law to it, which would show that $x \notin D \lor x \notin C \rightarrow x \notin A \lor x \notin B$. Obviously from here, we assume that $ x \notin D$, and from the contrapositive we see that x doesn't belong in B.

For my thinking above, how would I turn this into a proof if correct?

Comment: If $x\in A\setminus B$ then $x\in A\land x\notin B$

Comment: You can look at the contrapositive since it is logically equivalent to $p\to q$

Comment: I presume you mean $x \in A$.

Comment: @TehRod so I am allowed to turn the givens into anything equivalent?

Comment: @user2793618 yes

Comment: huh that's cool. so would my thinking above be correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

Note that $A \setminus B \subset D$.

$A = (A \cap B) \cup ( A \setminus B)$, this is a disjoint union.

We have $A \subset (A \cap B) \cup D$.

Hence if $x \in A$, we must have $x \in A \cap B$ or $x \in D$.

Since $x \notin D$, we must have $x \in A \cap B \subset B$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I more or less follow that you've written but what's the difference between $ \subseteq \ and \ \subset$ also what is a disjoint union and why can you do $ A = (A \cap B) \cup ( A \setminus B)$?

Comment: Some folks use $\subseteq$ to emphasise that it may be equality. A disjoint union means the to sets above that make up $A$ are disjoint. If $x \in A$ then either it is also in $B$ or it is not. That is $x \in A \cap B$ or $x \in A \subset B$.

Comment: oh I see thanks!

Comment: I had a few typos. in my comment, the worst was the last I should have $x \in A \setminus B$.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this by contradiction?

Suppose $ A \setminus B \subseteq C \cap D $ and $ x \in A $.

Suppose further that $ x \notin D $ and $  x \notin B $.

Since $ x \in A $ and $ x \notin B $,   $x \in A \setminus B $. 

Since $ A \setminus B \subseteq C \cup D $,   $ x \in C \cup D $ ... i.e. $ x \in C $ and $ x \in D $.

Since we assumed that $ x \notin D$, this is a contradiction.

Thus, if $ x \notin D $ then $ x \in B$.